# Gin, Get form-data nested object sending with postman

Tags: go, go-gin

So basically I want to use `PostFormMap()` method to get my data sent from postman's `form-data` but I get unexpected result and the reason that I'm not using `raw json` is that I want to upload a file too
Here is my postman

[image]

here is the code (nothing fancy)

```golang
c.JSON(200, gin.H{
    "request": c.PostFormMap("rules"),
})
```

and I'm expecting to get

```json
{
    "request": [
        {
            "cell": "A",
            "rule": "B"
        },
        {
            "cell": "B",
            "rule": "D"
        }
    ]
}
```

but instead I get this

```json
{
    "request": {
        "0": "B",
        "1": "D"
    }
}
```

### The question is how can I get the correct result?

Comment: I am not familiar with `gin` but I believe you shouldn't use `PostFormMap` on list. Maybe [Context.GetPostFormArray](https://sourcegraph.com/github.com/gin-gonic/gin/-/docs#Context.GetPostFormArray) cloud help.

Comment: @medasx thanks for the reply, already tried that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

###### Answering my own question

After spending hours of searching and having `PHP` background in my mind I realized that having such `form-data` parameter like `foo[0][bar]` manually implemented in `PHP` and is not a standard thing so in my case I decided to send the second parameter as a raw json
so it would be

**Postman `Body => form-data`**

| Key | Value |
| --- | --- |
| file | sample.xlsx |
| rules | [{"cell": "A", "rules": "string"}, {"cell": "B", "rules": "numeric"}] |